# vim ultisnips plugin doesn't work

Tags: vim, archlinux, ultisnips

i'm use `vim` on `arch linux` and ultisnips plugin doesn't work for my even i tried to use neocomplete and YCM but they don't work for me too, what can i do?

```
ENV:  
OS: ArchLinux  
VIM: 7.4
```

> $ vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov  7 2015 15:52:14)
Included patches: 1-909
Compiled by adham@localhost
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    +xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic   -Wl,-R/home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -L/home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -lruby -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/home/adham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib
```

my vim config files:
https://github.com/adham90/dotfile/blob/master/.vimrc
https://github.com/adham90/dotfile/tree/master/.vim/startup

> **.vimrc**

```
set nocompatible
filetype on
filetype indent on

"===== Load =====
source ~/.vim/startup/plugins.vim
source ~/.vim/startup/abbreviations.vim
source ~/.vim/startup/commands.vim
source ~/.vim/startup/functions.vim
source ~/.vim/startup/settings.vim
source ~/.vim/startup/mappings.vim
```

> **.setting.vim**

```
let mapleader = ","

"================================
" neocomplete
"================================
"================================

"================================
" UltiSnips
"================================
" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = "<C-l>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = "<C-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = "<C-k>"

"let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
"let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
"let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
"========================================

let g:pymode_rope_lookup_project = 0
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['coffee', 'css', 'erb=eruby', 'javascript', 'js=javascript', 'json=javascript', 'ruby', 'sass', 'xml', 'html'] " Specific configurations
let g:move_key_modifier = 'C'

"========================================
" General
"========================================
set cursorline
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set gdefault
set list
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬,nbsp:⋅,trail:•
set noswapfile
set smartindent
set paste
set shell=zsh
set relativenumber
set backspace=indent,eol,start   " enable <BS> for everything
set colorcolumn=80               " visual indicator of column
set number                       " Show line numbers
set hidden                       " hide when switching buffers, don't unload
set laststatus=2                 " always show status line
set lazyredraw                   " don't update screen when executing macros
set mouse=a                      " enable mouse in all modes
set nowrap                       " disable word wrap
set showbreak="+++ "             " String to show with wrap lines
set showcmd                      " show command on last line of screen
set showmatch                    " show bracket matches
set textwidth=0                  " don't break lines after some maximum width
set ttyfast                      " increase chars sent to screen for redrawing
set title                        " use filename in window title
set wildmenu                     " enhanced cmd line completion
set wildchar=<TAB>               " key for line completion
set noerrorbells                 " no error sound
set splitright                   " Split new buffer at right
set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
"========================================

"========================================
" Appearance
"========================================
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
set term=screen-256color
set winheight=999
set winheight=5
set winminheight=5
set winwidth=84
colorscheme Tomorrow-Night
syntax enable
"========================================

"========================================
" Folding
"========================================
set foldlevel=99
set foldignore=           " don't ignore anything when folding
set foldlevelstart=99     " no folds closed on open
set foldmethod=marker     " collapse code using markers
set foldnestmax=1         " limit max folds for indent and syntax methods
"========================================

"========================================
" Searches
"========================================
set hlsearch            " highlight search results
set incsearch           " search whilst typing
set ignorecase          " case insensitive searching
set smartcase           " override ignorecase if upper case typed
set more                " Stop in list
"========================================

"========================================
" StatusLine
"========================================
set statusline=%1*[%{GetName()}]\
set statusline+=%<pwd:%{getcwd()}\
set statusline+=%2*%{&modified?'\[+]':''}%*
set statusline+=%{IsHelp()}
set statusline+=%{&readonly?'\ (ro)\ ':''}
set statusline+=[
set statusline+=%{strlen(&fenc)?&fenc:'none'}\|
set statusline+=%{&ff}\|
set statusline+=%{strlen(&ft)?&ft:'<none>'}
set statusline+=]\
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=c%c
set statusline+=,l%l
set statusline+=/%L\
hi User1 ctermbg=white    ctermfg=black   guibg=#89A1A1 guifg=#002B36
hi User2 ctermbg=red      ctermfg=white   guibg=#aa0000 guifg=#89a1a1
"========================================

"========================================
" Autocommands
"========================================
autocmd BufWritePre *.rb :%s/\s\+$//e " auto remove trailing whitespace in ruby files
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ru set filetype=ruby
au BufRead,BufNewFile [vV]agrantfile set filetype=ruby
au Bufread,BufNewFile *.md set filetype=markdown textwidth=79
au Bufread,BufNewFile *.markdown set textwidth=79
au Bufread,BufNewFile *.feature set filetype=cucumber " .feature files are Cucumber.
"========================================

"========================================
" BACKUP / TMP FILES
"========================================
if isdirectory($HOME . '/.vim/backup') == 0
    :silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/backup >/dev/null 2>&1
endif
set backupdir-=.
set backupdir+=.
set backupdir-=~/
set backupdir^=~/.vim/backup/
set backupdir^=./.vim-backup/
set backup
if isdirectory($HOME . '/.vim/swap') == 0
    :silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/swap >/dev/null 2>&1
endif
set directory=./.vim-swap//
set directory+=~/.vim/swap//
set directory+=~/tmp//
set directory+=.
"========================================

"========================================
" stores the state of previous session
"========================================
set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
if exists("+undofile")
    if isdirectory($HOME . '/.vim/undo') == 0
        :silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/undo > /dev/null 2>&1
    endif
    set undodir=./.vim-undo//
    set undodir+=~/.vim/undo//
    set undofile
endif
"========================================

"========================================
" Make sure Vim returns to the same line when you reopen a file.
"========================================
augroup line_return
    au!
    au BufReadPost *
        \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
        \     execute 'normal! g`"zvzz' |
        \ endif
    augroup END
"========================================
```

> **plugins.vim**

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

"===== search ======
Plug 'mileszs/ack.vim'
Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'tpope/vim-abolish'
Plug 'Shougo/vimfiler.vim'

"===== Git =========
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'mattn/Gist-vim'
Plug 'gregsexton/gitv'
Plug 'tpope/vim-git'

"===== Ruby ========
Plug 'tpope/vim-rails'
Plug 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
Plug 'tpope/vim-rake'
Plug 'tpope/vim-endwise'
Plug 'bruno-/vim-ruby-fold'
Plug 't9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter'
Plug 'tpope/vim-bundler'
Plug 'sunaku/vim-ruby-minitest'
Plug 'nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock'
Plug 'slim-template/slim-rails'
Plug 'kana/vim-vspec'
Plug 'thoughtbot/vim-rspec'
Plug 'rhysd/vim-vspec-matchers'
Plug 'rubycomplete.vim'

Plug 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
"dark colour scheme for Vim & gVim
Plug 'w0ng/vim-hybrid'
"Vim Markdown runtime files
Plug 'tpope/vim-markdown'
"This plugin started out as a set of personal mappings
Plug 'tpope/vim-ragtag'
"Is all about surroundings: parentheses, brackets, quotes, XML tags, and more.
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
"improves HTML & CSS workflow
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
"Vim script for text filtering and alignment
Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'
"Send command from vim to a running tmux session
Plug 'jgdavey/tslime.vim'
"Vim runtime files for Haml, Sass, and SCSS
Plug 'tpope/vim-haml'
"plugin for intensely orgasmic commenting
Plug 'The-NERD-Commenter'
"Fold markdown documents by section.
Plug 'nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding'
"extended % matching for HTML, LaTeX, and many other languages
Plug 'matchit.zip'
"plugin to display the indention levels with thin vertical lines
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
"Syntax highlighting for VIM
Plug 'slim-template/vim-slim'
"Create your own text objects
Plug 'kana/vim-textobj-user'
"A light and configurable statusline/tabline for Vim
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
"A vim plugin that simplifies the transition between multiline and single-line code
Plug 'AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim'
"A simple, easy-to-use Vim alignment plugin.
Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
"Plug to move lines and selections up and down
Plug 'matze/vim-move'
"Delete all vim buffers but the current one.
Plug 'BufOnly.vim'

Plug 'Shougo/unite.vim'
Plug 'Shougo/vimshell.vim'
Plug 'Shougo/vimproc.vim', {
\ 'build' : {
\     'windows' : 'tools\\update-dll-mingw',
\     'cygwin' : 'make -f make_cygwin.mak',
\     'mac' : 'make',
\     'linux' : 'make',
\     'unix' : 'gmake',
\    },
\ }


"====== ColorScheme ======
Plug 'guns/jellyx.vim'
Plug 'gosukiwi/vim-atom-dark'
Plug 'chriskempson/vim-tomorrow-theme'

"======== AutoComplete =======
"Plug 'Shougo/neocomplete.vim'
"Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
"Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet'
"Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'

call plug#end()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try another shortcut key.

Then:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file

Answer (score 0):

the problem in my vimrc file that i always enable paste, i just remove `set paste` and every thing is OK now :D